Django-Admin in aws ec2 ubuntu 24.04 using pyhton 3.6.8
For my django admin panel I used django-soft-admin-panel pip for UI, as my python runtime is 3.8 it didn't run, so I downgraded by python to 3.6 and developed the project, the ui and all other things are perfectly working in local.
I need to deploy the project in any of the aws services.
At first I used lambda, but lambda is only for runtime >= 3.8
then I used Elastic Beanstalk, ebs is only for runtime >= 3.7
then I deployed in EC2 with nginx and gunicorn but the project and server getting crashed.
Is there any solution?
